# How to send custom date to firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I want to send date to firestore timestamp field.I don't want to use timestamp.now(). The date should be the user selected date.
eg in firestore it should look like

dob: June 4, 1946 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+5:30

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the `toIso8601String` method ([docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/DateTime/toIso8601String.html)) contained in the `DateTime` class. Firebase loves that standard.